# envsubst based on string

Tags: shell, text, environment-variables

I have the following two lines in my text file

```
$MyEnv
someText$MyEnv
```

I want to use envsubst to only replace the second occurence of MyEnv variable. How can I use the string "someText" to distinguish between the first and second occurrence of the variable and substitute in env variable?

so `envsubst < file1 >file2`

```
file 2
$MyEnv
someTextValueofMyEnv
```

How is this possible

Answer (score 1):

The following code will substitute all environment variables on the second line of the input.  The requested [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) command is the only non-builtin that is used.

```
L=0
while read line; do
  L=$((L+1))
  if [ $L = 2 ]; then
    echo "$line" |envsubst
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < file1 > file2
```

Start reading with the last line since it dictates the inputs and outputs; the contents of `file1` are read line by line, populating `$line` for each iteration of the `while` loop.  The `echo` lines are piped into `file2`.

We have a line counter `$L` which increments at the beginning of the loop.  If we're on line 2, we send the line through `envsubst`.  Otherwise, we just report it.

You also asked how you could use the string "someText" to distinguish between occurrences.  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this, but consider this:

```
while read line; do
  # $line contains the string 'someText$MyEnv'
  # (literally: $line does not match itself when removing that string)
  if [ "$line" != "${line#*someText\$MyEnv}" ]; then
    echo "$line" |envsubst
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < file1 > file2
```

Note: `envsubst` will only substitute *exported* variables.  The `envsubst` command is not portable; it's part of [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) and it is *not* a part of either the [POSIX standard utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) or the [Linux Standard Base commands](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/command.html) (LSB).

To be fully portable (and fully using sh builtins!), you'd need to use `eval`, which is unsafe without lots of extra checks.